# Librería Números para el Desarrollo en R

Tags: base-de-datos, r

Estoy tratando de extraer datos de la base de datos Números para el Desarrollo del Banco Inter americano utilizando la librería en R ([Código Números para el desarrollo](https://github.com/EL-BID/Libreria-R-Numeros-para-el-Desarrollo)) sin embargo se genera un error, alguien identifica por que el código no funciona? estoy omitiendo algún paso necesario?

Este es el código que estoy utilizando

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("EL-BID/Libreria-R-Numeros-para-el-Desarrollo")
library(iadbstats) 


iadbmsearch(value= "ALL")[1:5,1:5]
```

El resultado de este código debería ser este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No obstante, obtengo el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//
(right here) ------^
```

Comment: Aparentemente hay algún problema en la API de la propia página del BID, estoy probando uno de los ejemplos que figuran en la documentación y da un error 404. Ver: https://api-data.iadb.org/metadata/country?searchtype=code&searchvalue=ABW&languagecode=en&responsetype=xml

Comment: Sí, de hecho hay un issue abierto desde 2018 en https://github.com/EL-BID/Libreria-R-Numeros-para-el-Desarrollo/issues y no ha sido atendido. Algunos de los data sets pueden bajarse completos, por ejemplo en https://mydata.iadb.org/Economics/Latin-Macro-Watch-Dataset/tbnd-z94f están las series completas de datos macro (~800Mb), esa podría ser una alternativa, menos práctica pero efectiva.

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en la url que debería tener el json. Si te vas al github de la librería iadbstats puedes ver el comportamiento de la función `iadbmsearch`. Lo tienes en  [este enlace](https://github.com/EL-BID/Libreria-R-Numeros-para-el-Desarrollo/blob/master/R/iadbsearch.R). La [url](https://api-data.iadb.org/metadata/indicator?searchtype=code&searchvalue=ALL&languagecode=EN&responsetype=json) que te genera debería contener un json pero no la encuentra. Por lo que cuando intenta parsear el contenido de la url de un objeto json a R (`jsonlite::fromJSON`) genera un error.